# how to send number query params in supertest request

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to test an API endpoint and for that I'm using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) request, the thing is that the endpint is geting the query param as string (but as you can see it is a number)

```
request('http:///the-url.com/some-path')
    .get("/")
    .query({ numberProperty: 1 })
```

when I send the request using for example postman it is working correctly but when the endpoint receive the request from the test the type is string therefore the test is failing and getting a 400 because of the type validation

Comment: Aren't query params values always send as a string? Postman may be doing some parsing along the way.

Comment: If I use a browser it is working as expected too I don't know what should a do in order to get it working from the test

Comment: I was trying to browse around to check if that value can be sent as a `Number` but I wasn't able to find anything helpful